# Otimizar operação com lambda

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Tenho as seguintes classes:

```
public class Pedidos_Itens
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Qtde { get; set; }
    public Pedidos _Pedido { get; set; }
    public int Pedido { get; set; }
    public Loja_Produtos _Produto;
    public int Produto { get; set; }
}
```

E

```
public class Loja_Produtos
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
 }
```

E

```
public class Pedidos
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public decimal Valortotal { get; set; }
}
```

Porém no banco não tem chave estrangeira e não posso modificar NADA do banco. Assim não consigo utilizar o include (acredito que é por causa da ausencia da chave estrangeira). Então fiz o seguinte:

```
    public IEnumerable<Pedidos_Itens> ListarTodos()
    {
        var itens = contexto.PedidoItem.ToList();
        var list = new List<Pedidos_Itens>();
        foreach (var i in itens)
        {
            i._Produto = contexto.Produto.First(x => x.ID == i.Produto);
            i._Pedido = contexto.Pedido.First(x => x.ID == i.Pedido);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Porém acredito que tenha uma maneira mais eficiente de fazer o mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Exemplo:***

Como você mesmo relatou que não tem chave, então, foi feito um inner join nessas tabelas e o resultado será uma lista.

```cs
var resposta = contexto.Pedidos_Itens
                .Join(contexto.Loja_Produtos, pi => pi.Produto, l => l.ID, (pi, l) => new { pi, l })
                .Join(contexto.Pedidos, p => p.pi.Pedido, pe => pe.ID, (p, pe) => new { p, pe })
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    Loja_Produtos_ID = s.p.l.ID,
                    Loja_Produtos_NOME = s.p.l.Nome,
                    Pedidos_Itens_ID = s.p.pi.ID,
                    Pedidos_Itens_QTDE = s.p.pi.Qtde,
                    Pedidos_ID = s.pe.ID,
                    Pedidos_DATA = s.pe.Data, 
                    Pedidos_VALORTOTAL = s.pe.Valortotal
                });
```

A consulta com certeza é lenta, pela falta como relatado de chaves e relacionamentos e falta de indexação, mas, funciona de um certo modo até favorável.

**Com** [**Linq to Objects**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx):

```cs
public IEnumerable<Pedidos_Itens> ListarTodos()
{
    contexto contexto = new ConsoleApplication1.contexto();
    var resposta = contexto.Pedidos_Itens
        .Join(contexto.Loja_Produtos, pi => pi.Produto, l => l.ID, (pi, l) => new { pi, l })
        .Join(contexto.Pedidos, p => p.pi.Pedido, pe => pe.ID, (p, pe) => new { p, pe })
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Loja_Produtos_ID = s.p.l.ID,
            Loja_Produtos_NOME = s.p.l.Nome,
            Pedidos_Itens_ID = s.p.pi.ID,
            Pedidos_Itens_QTDE = s.p.pi.Qtde,
            Pedidos_ID = s.pe.ID,
            Pedidos_DATA = s.pe.Data,
            Pedidos_VALORTOTAL = s.pe.Valortotal
        });

    IList<Pedidos_Itens> ListaPedidosItens = new List<Pedidos_Itens>();
    foreach (var resp in resposta)
    {
        ListaPedidosItens.Add(new Pedidos_Itens()
        {
            ID = resp.Pedidos_Itens_ID,
            Qtde = resp.Pedidos_Itens_QTDE,
            _Pedido = new Pedidos() { ID = resp.Pedidos_ID, Data = resp.Pedidos_DATA, Valortotal = resp.Pedidos_VALORTOTAL },
            _Produto = new Loja_Produtos() { ID = resp.Loja_Produtos_ID, Nome = resp.Loja_Produtos_NOME }
        });
    }
    return ListaPedidosItens.AsEnumerable();
}
```

***Obs:*** *Não é muito usual fazer isso, mas, com [Linq to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), você vai simular a mesma coisa que se tivesse chaves e relacionamentos, não muito performática, mas funcional*

**Porque melhor?**

Vai executar uma única *SQL* com *Inner Join* e depois em memória será trabalhada os dados com [Linq to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx).

Comment: Mas como faço isso virar uma lista da classe Pedidos_Itens?

Comment: Deixa eu perguntar por cima? Qual o intuito ?

Comment: Por que faz parte do método  public Enumerable<Pedidos_Itens> ListarTodos(){} .

Comment: Porque, faz parte não me ofereceu um resposta apropriada, mas, @DiegoZanardo, fiz uma edição colocando a maneira mais próxima do ideal.

Comment: Este método faz parte da camada do repositório e a mesma incorpora uma interface que garante que irá retornar um método com essa assinatura.

Comment: Entendido @DiegoZanardo, inclusive edite a resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que isso irá atender.

```
var itens = contexto.PedidoItem.Select(pi => new
{
    ID = pi.ID,
    Qtde = pi.Qtde,
    Produto = pi.Produto,
    _Produto = contexto.Produto.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.ID == pi.Produto),
    Pedido = pi.Pedido,
    _Pedido = contexto.Pedido.FirstOrDefault(pe => pe.ID == pi.Pedido)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Aconteceu o seguinte erro: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'RepositorioEF.Pedidos_Itens' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo experimente tirar o tipo `Pedidos_Itens` que estou dando new, e faça um Dynamic object. Se isso funcionar, a performance estará sendo tão otimizada quanto.

Comment: acho que problema é que existem produtos dentro de PedidoItem, que não existem mais na tabela produto.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo tente então usar `.FirstOrDefault` ao invés de `.First`